# how to select max value with corresponding id in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    id
  , insId
  , MAX(avgRating) as avgRating 
FROM reviews 
WHERE status='1' 
GROUP BY insId
```

this query returns all reviews grouped by insId but id is not corresponding to this.

Comment: Try GROUP_CONCAT(id)

Comment: @DavidPartyka `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` will give all id's concated within the insId group most likely this won't generate the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a self INNER JOIN to get the results you need.

```
SELECT
   reviews.id
 , reviews_max.insId
 , reviews_max.maxAvgRating
FROM (

  SELECT 
     insId
   , MAX(avgRating) AS maxAvgRating
  FROM
   reviews
  WHERE
   status = '1'
  GROUP BY
   insId
) AS reviews_max
INNER JOIN 
 reviews
ON
   reviews.insId = reviews_max.insId 
 AND
   reviews.avgRating = reviews_max.maxAvgRating
```

Comment: this one selects with duplicate insId how to get distinct insId here?

Comment: What MySQL version? @kumar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    id
  , insId
  , MAX(avgRating) as avgRating 
FROM reviews 
WHERE status='1' 
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
SELECT id, 
insId, 
MAX(avgRating) as avgRating 
FROM reviews 
WHERE status='1' 
GROUP BY id, insId
```

Comment: it selects all reviews but i want only max avgRating value so it not work to me.